# Centered Bootstrap Navigation with centered logo in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap navbar with two different menus. One centered and one on the right. The logo is displayed on the left.

In the mobile view, both menus are collapsed. This is the only way, i get the desktop view working the way i want to.

But what i really want in the mobile view is to have the collapse button on the left, the logo centered and the second menu on the right.

Is there a good way to archieve that?

**Desktop View:** | LOGO | MENU 1 | MENU 2 |

**Mobile View:** | MENU 1 COLLAPSE-BUTTON | LOGO | MENU 2 |

Here is my actual code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Collapse</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand" title=""><img src="LOGO" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            /// MENU 1 - Mobile view collapsed
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            /// MENU 2 - Mobile view right
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, but it requires custom CSS to effect the collapse `navbar`..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle navbar-link pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsed-navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

**Working demo**: http://www.bootply.com/pOdynPWRbt

Answer (score 1):

well i dont know the proper way but i think below solution should work

create a div and place  | LOGO | MENU 1 |  in that div and make it float left.

now in media query for mobile just make logo float right and it will solve your problem

Desktop View:| | LOGO | MENU 1 || MENU 2 |

Mobile View: || MENU 1 COLLAPSE-BUTTON | LOGO || MENU 2 |